# How to Create a TCP Client connection with a Client Certificate in Powershell

Tags: ssl, powershell, sslstream, system.net.sockets

With Following code i can establish a SSL Connection:

```
   $cert = dir cert:\CurrentUser\My | where {$_.Subject -like "*Alice*"}

   $computerName = "google.com"
   $port = "443"

   $socket = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient($computerName, $port)
   $stream = $socket.GetStream()

   $sslStream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream $stream,$false
   $sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($computerName)


    $sslStream
```

This Works fine. But now i wan't to add a Client Certificate for Authentication. 
Think i just need to substitute

```
$sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($computerName)
```

with

```
$sslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient($computerName,$cert,"SslProtocols",$false,"Foo" ,"Bar")
```

But i wasn't lucky to get the Arguments right. Can Sombody solve the Assync Calls please ;-)
Maybe i need some C# code for this?!?

Arguments are:

```
System.IAsyncResult BeginAuthenticateAsClient(

string targetHost, 
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, 
System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols,
bool checkCertificateRevocation, 
System.AsyncCallback asyncCallback, 
System.Object asyncState)
```

What i finally want to achieve is to list and later specify the CipherSuites the client is connected to. (I could use Wireshark i know ;-) )

Comment: Sidenote:
i've read that System.Net.Security.SslStream might depend on .net FW 4 i enabled this on my testclient:
reg add hklm\software\microsoft\.netframework /v OnlyUseLatestCLR /t REG_DWORD /d 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it working, wasnt argument 4 but the $Cert which was no collection.

```
   $cert = dir cert:\CurrentUser\My | where {$_.Subject -like "*alice*"}

   $computerName = "google.com"
   $port = "443"

    [System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols]$protocol = "ssl3"

   $certcol = New-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection
   $certcol.Add($cert)




   $socket = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient($computerName, $port)
   $stream = $socket.GetStream()

   $sslStream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream $stream,$false
   #$sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($computerName)
   $sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($computerName,$certcol,$protocol,$false) 


    $sslStream
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the difference between `AuthenticateAsClient` and `BeginAuthenticateAsClient` is that the latter is for asynchronous use.

You should try [`AuthenticateAsClient(String, X509CertificateCollection, SslProtocols, Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145061.aspx), where the second argument is a collection of client certificates that can be used (preferably `X509Certificate2`, since you'll need the private key associated with the certificate for it to be usable for authentication).

Comment: ;-) I schould do my research on MSDN with .Net 4 FW  i just saw: 
the AuthenticateAsClient(string) method. I will test.

Comment: #Added: 
[System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols]$protocol = "ssl3"

#But my call: 
$sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($computerName,$cert,$protocol,$false)

Gives me back the Error: Cannot find an overload for "AuthenticateAsClient" and the argument count: "4".